# Histogram from nested list in R

Tags: r, histogram, nested-lists

I have a nested list similar to this

```
df <- data.frame(width = c(1:5),height = c(1:5),depth = c(1:5))
list <- list(df,df*2,df*5,df*1.3)
```

I would like to make a histogram, in either base R or ggplot, of the final height of each list. I have tried

```
hist(tail(list[[1:4]]$height,1))
```

which yields

```
Error in list[[1:4]] : recursive indexing failed at level 3
```

as well as

```
for (i in 1:4){
hist(tail(list[[i]]$height,1))
}
```

which generates 4 separate histograms of a single observation. I am trying to avoid simply listing each observation in `hist()` like

```
hist(tail(list[[1]]$height,1),tail(list[[2]]$height,1),tail(list[[3]]$height,1))
```

because my actual data has many more than 4 sub-lists. How can I achieve this elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to extract the last element of 'height', loop over the `list` with `sapply`, extract (`$`) the column 'height', get the `tail` value (`sapply` - returns a `vector` here) and then apply the `hist`

```
hist( sapply(list, function(x) tail(x$height, 1)))
```